# Instalar patch pro R

Tags: r, patch

Conforme documentado [aqui](http://biostatmatt.com/archives/456), a função iconv do R não funciona a contento. Felizmente, foi desenvolvido um patch que resolve o problema (aparentemente).

Minha dúvida é básica: como instalo o patch?

No [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267099/r-write-csv-with-utf-16-encoding), há uma resposta que aponta para a solução do patch.

Minhas infos:

> R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
>
> MAC OSX 10.9.5
>
> Platforma: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Não é exatamente a resposta para a sua pergunta, mas já tentou usar o `stringi`. Nele tem uma função `stri_encode` que resolve muitos problemas que tem no `iconv`.

Comment: Inclusive na documentação ele fala: `These two functions aim to replace R's iconv. It is not only faster, but also works in the same manner on all platforms.` e fala alguma coisa desse problema do vazio: `If str is a character vector and from is either missing, "", or NULL, then the declared encodings...`

Comment: Para atualizar o R basta fazer o download da versão mais nova do CRAN e instalar, como da primeira vez. Não existe procedimento especial para atualizar.

Comment: @DanielFalbel, por favor poste seu comentário como uma resposta. Acredito que está correta e servirá para outros usuários.

Comment: @FlavioBarros acho que o meu comentário não responde a pergunta do Manoel, é apenas uma saída para o contexto que ele deu... A pergunta dele " como faço para instalar o pacth no R?" não foi respondida...

Comment: No caso, o patch em questão modifica uma função interna do R. O link citado dá duas alternativas, aplicar o patch **diretamente no código-fonte do _R_** (tanto em um dos arquivos escritos em _R_ quanto em um dos arquivos escritos em _C_), quanto simplesmente compilar usando o código em C uma **nova _iconv_** como um programa externo e em uma sessão do R, salvar os dados em um arquivo e, então, usando a função `system` invocar esse **programa iconv** de dentro do _R_. Instalar o _R_ a partir do código-fonte em Windows não é algo exatamente simples. Mesmo o OP usando MacOS, a segunda alternativa

Comment: ... a segunda alternativa me parece melhor já que a versão mais atual do _R_ é a 3.3.1 e, se ele não pode ir para a mais nova, não me parecee sensato mexer no código-fonte de uma antiga.